# App crashes (React-Native) on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios

My App is crashing in Android

The way I see all my code is set.

What is the cause of the problem?

I checked everywhere but I see no problem in my code.

Please, where am I wrong?

**Below is my Console Error:**

```
Running application "CatalogueApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
Debugger and device times have drifted by more than 60s. Please correct this by running adb shell "date `date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S`" on your debugger machine.
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `AlbumList`. -keys for more information.
    in AlbumDetails (at AlbumList.js:19)
    in AlbumList (at index.android.js:22)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at index.android.js:20)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:100)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

**Below are my scripts Which the error is:**

**1.AlbumDetail.js.**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image} from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from "./CardSection";

const AlbumDetails = ({album}) => {
    //destructuring our props
    const {title,artist,thumbnail_image,image} = album;
    const {thumbnailStyle,headerContentStyles,thumbnailContainerStyle} = styles;

    return (

        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <View style={thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                    <Image  style={thumbnailStyle} source={{uri : thumbnail_image}}/>
                </View>
                <View style={headerContentStyles}>
                    <Text>{title}</Text>
                    <Text>{artist}</Text>
                </View>
            </CardSection>
            <CardSection>
                   <Image source={{uri :image}}/>
            </CardSection>

        </Card>
    );


}

const styles = {
    headerContentStyles: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'

    },
    thumbnailStyle:{
        height:50,
        width:50
    },
    thumbnailContainerStyle:{
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        marginLeft:'10',
        marginRight:'10'


    }
}

export default AlbumDetails;
```

**2.AlbumList**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail';

class AlbumList  extends Component {

    state ={albums:[]};

    componentWillMount(){
       // console.log('Component will mount in 2 ..')
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data}));
    }


    renderAlbums(){
        return this.state.albums.map(album =>
            <AlbumDetail  album={album}/>
        );
    }
       render(){

        //console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderAlbums()}

        </View>
    );
}
}

export default AlbumList;
```

Comment: Looks like the 2nd Image tag in your AlbumDetails component is closed twice: <Image/> source={{uri :image}}/>

Comment: man thanks ,  i corrected it but still crashing

Comment: oops...ignore my last comment...deleted

Comment: man still stuck , i have spent now 2 days without any idea of this error

Comment: can you add `key` prop to `<AlbumDetail  album={album}/>` please. must be unique for each child.

Comment: @bennygenel,i dont think that's the issue causing to act like that.Maybe you show me how?

Comment: you mean i do like this  `<AlbumDetail album={key.album}/> `

Comment: @huxaiphaerIdris Probobly its not because of that but just to be sure do something like that `<AlbumDetail key={album.title + album.artist} album={album} />`

Answer (score 0):

alter your `renderAlbums` function to include key

```
renderAlbums(){
    return this.state.albums.map((album, index) => 
        <AlbumDetail key={index}  album={album} />
    );
}
```

also marginLeft & marginRight values are numbers not strings

```
thumbnailContainerStyle:{
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    marginLeft: 10, // instead of '10'
    marginRight: 10, // instead of '10'
}
```

Comment: it still crashes

Comment: I updated my answer & tested the code it is working now with me

Comment: @huxaiphaerIdris if it is not worked with you pleaseinclude your card & cardSection files